# data base caching strategies for range pagination

Tags: java, mysql, database, caching

Need advice on caching and paging. Scenario  goes like this.. 
 User give to variable range (say variable X from x1 to x2 and Y from y1 to y2) and I fetch the data from database, after that  some logic do ordering on this result and give first page to user back..

For every user these (X & Y) are different. 
Problem start when user ask for second page i have to fire the query and order the result again and give the second page result.

This has to be done for each user request.. 
Can u suggest me any caching strategies for this.. 
(Java + mysql)
If I am not clear do let me know...

Comment: One more thing to mention that range of variable can overlap the with other user request.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `hibernate` for DB acccess you can allow `second_level_caching` to get EhCache caching your results automatically. Read more on this [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html)

Comment: but still I have to sorting on query result to find the next page.. can i can have some marker , or can store IDs list ??

Comment: With hibernate you may still sort on QURERY level using `ORDER BY`

Comment: you want ordering on applicaton (not DB) level?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that a user can make a request for eg x1 to x100 and get 100 results, and you want to display results paginated with eg 10 results at time.

I have three suggestions, each with various merits.

**Rely on MySQL to do the caching.**
MySQL is pretty good at caching. If you repeat the same query a number of times, then MySQL will try and cache the results for you, making subsequent queries very fast (they come from memory and don't touch disk). If you query x1 to x100 and just display x1 to x10, then when you want to display page 2 you query x1 to x100 again MySQL can use its own internal cache. MySQL caching obviously uses RAM, so you need to ensure your DB server has enough RAM to be able to cache effectively. You will have to estimate how much data you expect to be caching and see if this is feasible.

This is an easy solution and hardware (RAM) is fairly cheap*.

**Cache internally**
Save the whole x1 to x100 results in your application (for eg in a user session) and display the relevant result for the page requested. This is similar to using MySQL to cache, but you are moving the cache closer to where it is needed. If you do this you have to think about things like cache management yourself (eg when to expire cache, managing memory use). You can use existing caching tools like ehcache for this.

**Prefetch instead of caching**
Caching requires a lot of memory. If caching isn't feasible then you might want to consider a prefetch strategy. With no caching you might experience slow response times but the problem is somewhat alleviated with a prefetch. This is where after a user has viewed one page you do an async look up of other pages the user is likely to view (usually next and previous). The lookup may be slow but you are doing it *before the user has asked for it* so its ready immediately when they need it.

Prefetching is a fairly common technique in web applications; when a user views a page the application can use ajax to load the prev and next pages into the DOM behind the scenes while the user is viewing the current page. When the user clicks the 'next' link the application modifies the DOM to show the next page without having to touch the server at all. To the user it looks like the response is instant.

*I was once on a MySQL administration course and on the topic of performance the tutor said the first thing *anyone* should do is fit as much RAM to the server as it supports. Most servers can be filled with RAM (were talking 100s of Gb) for less that the cost of a 3 day performance tuning course.

Comment: I will go with your second option .. firing query is not a big deal, logical ordering is what killing time.. I want to cache that x100 result and can give next page.. Prefetch will not work in my case.. because i have to load 100 result that make them in order. .so on next page I still need first 10 for making proper ordering , other wise no way to know, which 10 result has gone in first page...

Comment: one more thing i want to bring in front what i have mention in comment of question. that this range of variable can be  overlap with each other , SO if i can have some data structure to store this info in range format, so that for other user also i can map in other user result.. I know my language in some what fuzzy in explains my problem.. do let me know what part is not understandable..